# No wireless connection on new install

Tags: wireless, 14.04

Okay guys. I know that these problems can get super specific and I've looked around at questions with similar problems and I'm just not finding it.

I am brand spanking new to Linux. Keep that in mind.

I have a dual boot MacBook Pro that I just got done with yesterday. At first, the wireless connection was fine, but today I started having problems. I know it's not a hardware issue with the laptop itself as I am typing this and asking this using OS X right now. Anywho, the trouble is that whenever I boot Ubuntu (14.04), the wireless connection works for probably five or ten minutes. It gets super slow. And then it dies all together. The icon indicator for the wireless connection still says that I'm connected this whole time, but nothing loads and I'm at a loss.

Help?

Thanks in advance.